# How to covert projection "102719 = NAD 1983 StatePlane North Carolina FIPS 3200 Feet" to latitude and longitude in jMapProgLib?

Tags: java, gis

I have an assignment to convert coordinates in North Carolina state plane to Latitude and Longitude.

EX: 2_329_394.77272739, 524_784.10055898  converts to  -77.8975142, 35.1869162
See:  https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=102719&t_srs=4326&x=2329394.7727274&y=524784.1005590

I started with jMapProjLib.  But not getting the correct answer.

Here is my code in jUnit test form:

```
@Test
public void testLCCProjection() {
    System.out.println("getLCCProjection");

    // From \coordsys\esri file in project.  Line 5703
    //# NAD 1983 StatePlane North Carolina FIPS 3200 Feet
    //<102719>   +proj=lcc +lat_1=34.33333333333334 +lat_2=36.16666666666666 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +x_0=609601.2199999999 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192  no_defs <>
    String[] args = new String[]{
        "+proj=lcc", // projection name is Lambert Conformal Conic
        "+lat_1=34.33333333333334", // projectionLatitude 1
        "+lat_2=36.16666666666666", // projectionLatitude 2
        "+lat_0=33.75", // projectionLatitude
        "+lon_0=-79", // projectionLongitude
        "+x_0=609601.2199999999", // falseEasting in meters. This is the correct value.
        // "+x_0=2000000.002616666", // falseEasting in feet
        "+y_0=0", // falseNorthing
        "+ellps=GRS80", //
        "+datum=NAD83", //
        "+to_meter=0.3048006096012192", // conversion to meters.
    };

    // lccp stands for  LamberConformalConicProjection
    Projection lccp = ProjectionFactory.fromPROJ4Specification(args);
    lccp.initialize();

    // input
    double x = 2_329_394.77272739;  // in feet
    double y = 524_784.10055898;   // in feet
    // the correct answer  see:  https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=102719&t_srs=4326&x=2329394.7727274&y=524784.1005590
    double expectedLong = -77.8975142D;
    double expectedLat = 35.1869162D;

    // convert to meters
    double toMeters = 0.3048006096012192;
    double x_in_meters = x * toMeters;
    double y_in_meters = y * toMeters;
    Point2D.Double out = new Point2D.Double();
    Point2D.Double in = new Point2D.Double();
    in.x = x_in_meters;
    in.y = y_in_meters;

    // run the inverse transform.  The magic happens here!
    lccp.inverseTransform(in, out);

    // verify the answer
    double longitude = out.x;
    double latitude = out.y;
    System.out.println("lat/Long expected = " + expectedLat + " " + expectedLong);
    System.out.println("lat/long in deg decimal = " + latitude + " " + longitude);
    System.out.println("diff lat/long = " + Math.abs(expectedLat - latitude) + " " + Math.abs(
            expectedLong - longitude));
    assertEquals(expectedLong, longitude, 0.1);
    assertEquals(expectedLat, latitude, 0.1);

}
```

This returns a point in Georgia.  It should be in North Carolina.

How to fix it?

Any help would be appreciated!!

Is there a better library or package to handle this conversion?

Output on System.out:

```
lat/Long expected = 35.1869162 -77.8975142
lat/long in deg decimal = 34.113370281502604 -83.26272018000135
diff lat/long = 1.0735459184973948 5.365205980001349
```

Comment: What were the outputs of System.out? Why do you have the step "convert to meters"? The [source SRS has `+units=us-ft`](http://epsg.io/102719.proj4). Also `+x_0=609601.2199999999` is in us-ft.

Comment: Output of System.out is added to the bottom of question text.

Comment: The value +x_0=609601.2199999999 (aka "False Easting") is in meters. The value for +x_0 in feet is +x_0=2000000.002616666. This has been added to the comments of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  The above works when the conversion of `x` and `y` to meters is removed.  I was so close.  Thanks to 'Mike T' for the suggestion.

Working Code:

```
    public void testLCCProjection() {
        System.out.println("getLCCProjection");

        // From \coordsys\esri file in project.  Line 5703
        //# NAD 1983 StatePlane North Carolina FIPS 3200 Feet
        //<102719>   +proj=lcc +lat_1=34.33333333333334 +lat_2=36.16666666666666 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +x_0=609601.2199999999 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +to_meter=0.3048006096012192  no_defs <>
        String[] args = new String[]{
            "+proj=lcc", // projection name is Lambert Conformal Conic
            "+lat_1=34.33333333333334", // projectionLatitude 1
            "+lat_2=36.16666666666666", // projectionLatitude 2
            "+lat_0=33.75", // projectionLatitude
            "+lon_0=-79", // projectionLongitude
            "+x_0=609601.2199999999", // falseEasting in meters. This is the correct value.
            // "+x_0=2000000.002616666", // falseEasting in feet
            "+y_0=0", // falseNorthing
            "+ellps=GRS80", //
            "+datum=NAD83", //
            "+to_meter=0.3048006096012192", // conversion to meters.
        };

        // lccp stands for  LamberConformalConicProjection
        Projection lccp = ProjectionFactory.fromPROJ4Specification(args);
        lccp.initialize();

        // input
        double x = 2_329_394.77272739;  // in feet
        double y = 524_784.10055898;   // in feet
        // the correct answer  see:  https://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=102719&t_srs=4326&x=2329394.7727274&y=524784.1005590
        double expectedLong = -77.8975142D;
        double expectedLat = 35.1869162D;
        // double toMeters = 0.3048006096012192;

        Point2D.Double out = new Point2D.Double();
        Point2D.Double in = new Point2D.Double();
        in.x = x;
        in.y = y;

        // run the inverse transform.  The magic happens here!
        lccp.inverseTransform(in, out);

        // verify the answer
        double longitude = out.x;
        double latitude = out.y;
        System.out.println("lat/Long expected = " + expectedLat + " " + expectedLong);
        System.out.println("lat/long in deg decimal = " + latitude + " " + longitude);
        System.out.println("diff lat/long = " + Math.abs(expectedLat - latitude) + " " + Math.abs(
                expectedLong - longitude));
        assertEquals(expectedLong, longitude, 0.1);
        assertEquals(expectedLat, latitude, 0.1);

    }
```

Output on System.out:

```
lat/Long expected = 35.1869162 -77.8975142
lat/long in deg decimal = 35.18691619350664 -77.89751408312104
diff lat/long = 6.493358739589894E-9 1.16878965172873E-7
```

Yea!